# Sticky Header issue with deep links

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with my sticky header overlapping with my deep links. If I have a deep link, the default browser behavior is to scroll the top of the browser viewport to the exact position of the target element id.  Unfortuntely, this causes the sticky header to overlap and cover the target element id.

I've tried to use JQuery's `scrollTop()` method to scroll to the target element's position, with an offset for the header, but the result is very inconsistent.

I've even tried to check for the browser's scroll before executing my custom scroll with an offset for the sticky nav, but it seems like my scroll function still collides with the browser's native scroll and gives inconsistent results, meaning sometimes the browser's native scroll executes after mine, even after using a timeout of 100-500ms to set up a delay.

I need to support IE8+ and all modern browsers.  Is there a way I can prevent the browser's default scroll?  Open to any ideas.  Looking for a JS solution as all CSS based solutions have major drawbacks (ie target element cannot have border top, background, etc.)

Comment: Kindly post code rather than long theories.